# Как вызвать material dialog в фрагменте?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-material-dialog-lib

1.В фрагменте код такой. Нужно что бы при нажатии на кнопку `button1` откривался диалог
[ссылка на саму библиотеку на Git hub](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs)

код фрагмента

```
    public class velstudent_Fragment extends Fragment  {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_secret, null);

    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.info)));


    Button button1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .title(R.string.app_name)
                    .content(R.string.infoprivichki)
                    .positiveText(R.string.drawer_close)
                    .negativeText(R.string.drawer_open)
                    .show();
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

}

при переходе в емуляторе на этот фрагмент выдает ошибку:

```
    10-27 13:33:53.264 30255-30255/com.whitestar.successstudent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 13:33:53.264 30255-30255/com.whitestar.successstudent E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 13:33:53.264 30255-30255/com.whitestar.successstudent E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.whitestar.successstudent.fragments.velstudent_Fragment.onCreateView(velstudent_Fragment.java:44)
10-27 13:33:53.264 30255-30255/com.whitestar.successstudent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1965)
10-27 13:33:53.264 30255-30255/com.whitestar.successstudent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1078)
10-27 13:33:53.264 30255-30255/com.whitestar.successstudent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1259)
10-27 13:33:53.264 30255-30255/com.whitestar.successstudent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
10-27 13:33:53.264 30255-30255/com.whitestar.successstudent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1624)
10-27 13:33:53.264 30255-30255/com.whitestar.successstudent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
10-27 13:33:53.264 30255-30255/com.whitestar.successstudent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-27 13:33:53.264 30255-30255/com.whitestar.successstudent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-27 13:33:53.264 30255-30255/com.whitestar.successstudent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-27 13:33:53.264 30255-30255/com.whitestar.successstudent E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-27 13:33:53.264 30255-30255/com.whitestar.successstudent E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 13:33:53.264 30255-30255/com.whitestar.successstudent E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-27 13:33:53.264 30255-30255/com.whitestar.successstudent E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-27 13:33:53.264 30255-30255/com.whitestar.successstudent E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-27 13:33:53.264 30255-30255/com.whitestar.successstudent E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 13:38:53.340 30255-30255/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30255 SIG: 9
```

код лайтлаута фрагмента:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mScroll2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:onClick="test1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            />
    </ScrollView>

    <Button                     // изменил буттон на етот
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mScroll2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
public class velstudent_Fragment extends Fragment  {

Button button1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_secret, null);

    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.info)));

    button1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .title(R.string.app_name)
                    .content(R.string.infoprivichki)
                    .positiveText(R.string.drawer_close)
                    .negativeText(R.string.drawer_open)
                    .show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Идея в том, чтобы получать `Context` (т.е. getActivity()) в onResume(), когда фрагмент уже точно отображается.

Answer (score 3):

Все потому, что вы не посмотрели, параметр какого типа должен передаваться в метод `new MaterialDialog.Builder(...)`. Там параметр типа `Context`. Во `Fragment` `Context` можно получить при помощи, например `getActivity()`. То есть получится `new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())` вместо `new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)`

---

По поводу ошибки:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_big"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_big"
    android:background="@drawable/fab"/>
```

Тут у вас обьект типа `Button`
Дальше в коде:

```
ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

А тут вы пытаетесь найти (findViewById) объект типа `ImageButton`. Если вы в разметке указали `Button`, то и ищите `Button`. Замените

```
ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

на

```
Button button1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Comment: да помогло но... при запуске в емуляторе как только емулятор откривает приложение выскакивает диалог... + еще одна ошибка при переходе на етот фрагмент выкидает ошибку сейчас выше залью код @metalurgus

Comment: @Андрей, Почему сразу выскакивает диалог - смотрите сами. По поводу ошибки, что находится на 44 строке:`velstudent_Fragment.java:44`

Comment: с проблемой при запуске разобрался ... Но при переходе в емуляторе на этот фрагмент выдаеет ошибку выше выложил код + выложил код лайтлоута

Comment: @Андрей, прочитайте комментарий полностью. Что находится на 44 строке в файле `velstudent_Fragment.java`?

Comment: 2 раза перечитал @metalurgus чтото я непонимаю? да ошибка именно в строке 44

Comment: У вас `NullPointerException` на 44 строке в файле `velstudent_Fragment.java`. Я не вижу, что именно находится на этой строке, т. к. тут нету вашей номерации строк. Покажите мне 44 строку.

Comment: 44 строка @metalurgus  `button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

Comment: см. ответ. Обновил. И мой вам совет, если хотите что-либо серьезное делать, не тестируйте на эмуляторе. Только на реальном устройстве, да еще и не на одном, и на нескольких разных

Comment: ето кажется я уже дано исправил сейчас перезалью коды @metalurgus

Comment: посмотрите перезалил коды спасибо за совет, буду реальный тел подключать @metalurgus

Comment: @Андрей И что теперь находится на 44 строке?

Comment: тоже самое `button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

Comment: @Андрей, значит что-то не так с разметкой фрагмента. Значит в ней нет объекта типа `Button` и id `@+id/button`

Comment: разметку выложил уже @metalurgus сейчас перезалью

Comment: помогите пожалуйста , все равно неработает ошибка в 44 строке что делать

Comment: @Андрей, вы точно уверены, что это разметка `R.layout.fragment_secret`?